# Enable debug logs in Ballerina REST API project

Tags: debugging, ballerina

I'm working on a Ballerina REST API project and I want to enable debug logs for debugging and troubleshooting. How can I do this?

Specifically, I'm looking for information on:

1. How to configure the logging level to enable debug logs.
2. Any specific configuration files or settings that need to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

To enable debug logs in the project, we can set the `ballerina.log.level` configurable value to `DEBUG`.
As an example `bal run -- -Cballerina.log.level=DEBUG`

For more details and additional configuration options, we can refer to the [Ballerina logging configuration documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/logging-with-context/).